# Pass array on url using zend framework 2 routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I have a web app that lets user make multiple searches and show the results of that searches all on the same page.

Here's a basic structure:

```
Search 1
 - Attribute 1 = X
 - Attribute 3 = Y

Search 2
 -Attribute 2 = Z
```

All these results are loaded to my page using Ajax requests. The problem here is that if an user wants to show the results of the searches to someone, he wouldn't be able to do it because the url remains the same.

To fix this problem I'll probably use javascript push state or replace state: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

My problem is with Zend 2 reading these url and parse it. I would like to have something to be user friendly like this:

```
www.example.com/Search/Attribute1-X-Attribute3-Y/Search/Attribute2-Z
```

The idea is to receive something like this on my controller:

```
$this->getParam('Search');//Array('Attribute1-x-Attribute3-Y','Attribute2-Z');
```

I know we can accomplish something similar using it this way:

```
?a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3
```

But this are not the droids I'm looking for.

Any help on how to accomplish this using zf2 routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had no feedback I had to make a workaround. Here's how I managed to accomplish what I asked:

First, instead of using:

```
www.example.com/Search/Attribute1-X-Attribute3-Y/Search/Attribute2-Z
```

I used something like this:

```
www.example.com/Search/Attribute1/X/Attribute3/Y/Search/Attribute2/Z
```

I first used a regex to this route on my module.config:

```
'search' => array(
            'type' => 'Application\Router\SearchesImprovedRegex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '(/Search((/Attribute1/(?<attr1>[a-zA-Z-]+)){0,1}(/Attribute2/(?<attr2>[a-zA-Z-]+)){0,1}(/Attribute3/(?<attr3>[a-zA-Z-]+)){0,1}))+',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
                'spec'=> '/'
            ),
        ),
```

Then I created my own class that extended Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex and implemented RouterInterface. I just had to override the match function to make it parse the attributes a little bit differently.

```
<?php 
namespace Application\Router;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex as Regex;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
/**
* Regex route.
*/
class SearchesImprovedRegex extends Regex {

/**
 * match(): defined by RouteInterface interface.
 *
 * @param  Request $request
 * @param  int $pathOffset
 * @return RouteMatch|null
 */
public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null) {
    if (!method_exists($request, 'getUri')) {
        return null;
    }

    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = $uri->getPath();

    $auxPath = explode('/Search', $path);
    $searches = Array();


    for ($i = 1; $i < count($auxPath); $i++) {
        $search = array();
        $path = '/Search' . $auxPath[$i];

        if ($pathOffset !== null) {
            $result = preg_match('(\G' . $this->regex . ')', $path, $matches, null, $pathOffset);
        } else {
            $result = preg_match('(^' . $this->regex . '$)', $path, $matches);
        }

        if (!$result) {
            return null;
        }

        $matchedLength = strlen($matches[0]);

        foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key) || is_int($key) || $value === '') {
                unset($matches[$key]);
            } else {
                $search[$key] = rawurldecode($value);
            }
        }
        array_push($searches, $search);
    }
    $matches = Array('Searches' => $searches);

    return new RouteMatch(array_merge($this->defaults, $matches), $matchedLength);
}
}
```

Then on controller:

```
var_dump($this->params('Searches'));
```